# Deducing expected value using asymptotic probability distribution (Coupon Collector's problem)

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, coupon-collector

I am reading Erdős and Rényi's [*On a Classical Problem of Probability Theory*](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1961-09.pdf), where they derive the asymptotic distribution for the Coupon Collector's problem of collecting at least one of every type of coupon (more generally, they solve it for $m$ of each type). In particular, they prove that for the general problem, if the first time is denoted by $v_m(n)$,

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( v_m(n) < n\log n + (m-1) \log\log n + x \right) = \exp\left( -\frac{e^{-x}}{(m-1)!} \right) , \quad x \in \mathbb{R} .
$$

My question is about their remark on how this equation can be used to deduce that the expected value is

$$
\mathbb{E}[v_m(n)] = n \log n + (m-1) \log\log n + nC_m + o(n) ,
$$

and how it can also be used to deduce that the constant $C_m = \gamma - \log(m-1)!$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).

In the case $m = 1$, this fact follows from a simple computation of the expected value and the asymptotics of the harmonic series. But I am not too sure about the exact way you can use the asymptotic distribution to derive the expected value as the authors have remarked. Intuitively, I think it makes a lot of sense since this shows that $v_m(n)$ concentrates around $n\log n + (m-1)\log \log n + nC_m$ for some constant $C_m$, with $o(n)$ error.